# Segmentation fault: 11 - tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, segmentation-fault

Segmentation fault: 11 - not sure what it means, why it has happened. I thought it was an issue with Python on my machine by all other files run fine. I have, of course, tried restarting and re-installing Python but didn't help.

I'm just trying to implement frame switching via a menu bar with tkinter.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
# import tkinter modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkcalendar import *

# import modules for restart functionality
import os
import sys
import time


# define self
class tkinterApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # creating a container
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        # initialising frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {}

        menu_bar = Menu(container)

        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Main Menu", menu=menu_bar)
        menu_bar.add_command(label="Welcome page", command=lambda: self.show_frame(welcome_frame))
        menu_bar.add_command(label="Book a vehicle", command=lambda: self.show_frame(booking_frame))
        menu_bar.add_command(label="Register as new user", command=lambda: self.show_frame(register_frame))

        Tk.config(self, menu=menu_bar)

        for F in (welcome_frame, register_frame, booking_frame):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(welcome_frame)

        def show_frame(self, cont):
            frame = self.frames[cont]
            frame.tkraise()





class welcome_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # welcome_frame = Frame(self, width=1000, height=800)
        # welcome_frame.grid()

        welcome = Label(welcome_frame, text="Hello, please use the menu above to navigate the interface")
        welcome.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

class register_frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        welcome = Label(self, text="New user - enter your details below to use the Collyer's car park.")
        welcome.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)






class booking_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)


app = tkinterApp()
app.geometry("1000x800")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a cascade menu where the cascaded menu is the same menu:

```
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Main Menu", menu=menu_bar)
```

The `menu` option needs to point to a new menu menu.

```
main_menu = Menu(menu_bar)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Main Menu", menu=main_menu)
```

I'm guessing you also want to put the menu commands on that menu, too

```
main_menu.add_command(label="Book a vehicle", command=lambda: self.show_frame(booking_frame))
main_menu.add_command(label="Register as new user", command=lambda: self.show_frame(register_frame))
```

---

Unrelated to the question, this code is also wrong:

```
welcome = Label(welcome_frame, text="Hello, please use the menu above to navigate the interface")
```

You are trying to use a class as the parent/master of the `Label` widget. You can't do that. The first parameter needs to be a widget. In this case, it should be `self`.

You also need to make sure that `show_frame` is indented the same as the `__init__` method of the tkinterApp class.

Comment: How would I pass a variable value from one class to another? Would I have to declare it within every class constructor?